# Prove that $\lim_{x \rightarrow c} \frac{1}{f(x)}$ does not exist.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $ I \subset \mathbb{R}$ be an open interval and let $c \in I$ and $f:I-\left \{  c \right \} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function. Suppose that $f(x) \neq 0:\forall x \in I-\left \{  c \right \}$ , and that $\lim_{x \rightarrow c}f(x)=0$. Prove that $\lim_{x \rightarrow c} \frac{1}{f(x)}$ does not exist.

**Proof**

Suppose we assume that the limit exists. Then, 
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow c}f(x)= mc+b $$
$$ \implies \lim_{x \rightarrow c}\frac{1}{f(x)}= \frac{1}{mc+b} $$
Assume we have $f(x)=3x+2$ as our test function. So,
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow c} \frac{1}{f(x)}=\frac{1}{3c+2} $$

Do I need to find the positive and left limit for both sides? I'm confused on how to proceed?

Comment: limit does not exist finite?

Comment: why do you assume $\lim_{x \rightarrow c}f(x)= mc+b$?

Comment: Where is the $mc+b$ coming form?

Comment: Well, I proved before that $\lim_{x \rightarrow c}(mx+b)=mc+b$ So, I thought I could prove using this fact. The book also suggests this.

Comment: when we say that limit does not exist we mean that it doesn't exist at all. as for example $lim_{x\to+\infty} \sin x$, what do you mean here?

Comment: What kind of book are you using ?

Comment: Ethan Bloch's: Real Numbers and Real Analysis

Comment: First, why should this be true?  Well, if $f(x)$ is close to $0$, $1/f(x)$ must be very large in absolute value, right?  Now for the proof, start by writing down the definitions, and see how your intuition applies.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C>0$ be given. Then, choose $\epsilon >0$ such that 
$$
\frac{1}{\epsilon} \geq C
$$
Since $\lim_{x \to c}f(x)=0$, we can find $\delta >0$ such that $|x-c| <\delta$ implies $|f(x)| < \epsilon$. This implies:
$$
\frac{1}{|f(x)|} > \frac{1}{\epsilon} \geq C
$$
Thus, $\lim_{x \to c} \frac{1}{|f(x)|}= \pm \infty$ .

Can you take it from there?